# Cascading ComboBoxes within a Telerik GridView based on a SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, combobox, telerik

I am using Telerik in a WPF project. I have the following table:

| ID | Country | Plant | Area | Machine |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | DE | MUC | BA | A |
| 2 | DE | MUC | BA | B |
| 3 | AT | VIE | BE | 1 |
| 4 | AT | VIE | BE | 2 |

Now I would like to fill the ComboBox Plant in a cascading way, after updating the country looking up what Plants are possible for country DE f.e.

The same for the Area and Machine ComboBox.

I already tried several ways but I couldn't find a solution.

[image: Telerik RadGridView]

I have the following code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private SqlConnection connection;
    private string dbName = string.Empty;
    
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadData();
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        try
        {
            string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Test_DB;Integrated Security=True";

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.MachineAreas";
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
                DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(dataTable);

                gridMachineAreas.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void GridMachineAreas_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, GridViewAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {            
        switch ((e.Column as GridViewDataColumn).DataMemberBinding.Path.Path)
        {
            case "ID":
                var newColumn1 = new GridViewDataColumn();
                newColumn1.CopyPropertiesFrom(e.Column);
                newColumn1.Header = "ID";
                newColumn1.Width = 60;
                e.Column = newColumn1;
                break;

            case "Country":
                var newColumn2 = new GridViewComboBoxColumn();
                newColumn2.CopyPropertiesFrom(e.Column);
                newColumn2.Header = "Country";
                newColumn2.Width = 60;
                newColumn2.UniqueName = "Country";
                newColumn2.IsComboBoxEditable = false;
                newColumn2.ItemsSource = MakeCountryCollection();                    
                
                e.Column = newColumn2;
                break;

            case "Plant":
                var newColumn3 = new GridViewComboBoxColumn();
                newColumn3.CopyPropertiesFrom(e.Column);
                newColumn3.Header = "Plant";
                newColumn3.Width = 60;                    
                e.Column = newColumn3;
                break;

            case "Area":
                var newColumn4 = new GridViewComboBoxColumn();
                newColumn4.CopyPropertiesFrom(e.Column);
                newColumn4.Header = "Area";
                newColumn4.Width = 60;
                e.Column = newColumn4;
                break;

            case "Machine":
                var newColumn5 = new GridViewComboBoxColumn();
                newColumn5.CopyPropertiesFrom(e.Column);
                newColumn5.Header = "Machine";
                newColumn5.Width = 60;
                e.Column = newColumn5;
                break;
        }
    }

    private List<string> MakeCountryCollection()
    {
        List<string> countryCollection = new List<string>();
        string query = "SELECT Country FROM dbo.MachineAreas Group By Country";
        
        try
        {
            string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Test_DB;Integrated Security=True";

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            string value = reader.GetString(0);
                            countryCollection.Add(value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }

        return countryCollection;
    }
}
```

Any help or hint is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Telerik has actually addressed this directly themselves and have provided a great "How-To" type article here:

https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/knowledge-base/cascading-comboboxes-in-radgridview

Comment: Thank you. I didn't find that before andI think it will lead me to a good solution for my problem.

Comment: Good luck with your implementation and if it does indeed provide the solution you needed, please be sure to come back and mark as the answer so future searches turn up a solution.